# Non log-canonical Fano of Picard number 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is an example of a Fano variety of Picard number 1 that does not have log-canonical singularities?

Comment: Are singular hypersurfaces of low degree log-canonical? Because they are Fano with Picard number one...

Comment: Piotr, they don't need to be log canonical I don't think. Log canonical is basically a local version of Frobenius split. In other words, if you have a variety that is not *locally* Frobenius split for any p, then it is not log canonical either (at least up to some big conjectures).